# FreeBSD on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, freebsd

The Google Compute Engine [announcement](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.de/2013/12/google-compute-engine-is-now-generally-available.html) mentions support for RHEL, SUSE, and FreeBSD. On VM creation only Debian and CentOS are available. Is FreeBSD support still being worked on or do I need to create my own disk image to start with?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the future direction of a proprietary product which should really be directed to the GAE product team.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about support of a VM

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FreeBSD is now supported by the service, but images are not provided by Google. Paul Rashidi has posted detailed steps for [creating a FreeBSD image](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-discussion/YWoa3Aa_49U/FYAg9oiRlLUJ).

Later in the same thread, Dave Cottlehuber shares a tool he created to [make installation easier](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-discussion/YWoa3Aa_49U/1MfTsmgoaNkJ).

For RHEL and SUSE, there is a signup link in the [Premium Operating Systems](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/premium-operating-systems#prerequisites) documentation.

**update:** On June 9th, we published a video walking through the details of [How to build a custom image for Compute Engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlcR6ZLebTM).

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a script to build images for FreeBSD on Google Compute Engine, see:

https://plus.google.com/112202779615695172291/posts/eYajb8JKerY

for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Anther option for building images can be found here:

https://github.com/daveish/freebsd-gce-tools